# What is the matrix $P$ that accomplishes the equivalent operations in the row reduction steps?

Tags: linear-algebra

> The linear system is as follows:
>      $$ 2 + 3 − 4 = 10\\
>     5 + 2 +  = 20\\
>      − 6 + 3 = 12\\
> $$
>   Denote the matrix of coefficients for the left-hand side of the system of equations above as 
>   $$
> A =
> \begin{pmatrix}
>     2  &3  &−4\\
>     5  &2  &1\\
>     1 &−6  &3\\
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   Denote the matrix equivalent with the row reduced form of this matrix
>   as $R$. What is the matrix $P$ that accomplishes the equivalent operations in the row reduction steps that you performed for the previous questions? In other words, what is the matrix $P$ that satisfies $PA = R$ given $A$ and $R$?

I don't even know where to start with this. I have the row reduced matrix but I don't know what it wants me to do now? Could I get a first step?
(Apologies didn't think the equations were important since I had the matrix)

Comment: "I don't even know where to start with this." Have you seen any related/similar exercises/questions in your textbook or lecture notes?

Comment: The topic is "elementary matrices."  Each row operation is associated with a matrix $E$ such that multiplication by $E$ makes the wanted change in $A$.  The $P$ is the product of those elementary matrices.

Comment: A detailed answer is in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to row-reduce
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 3 & -4 \\
5 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & -6 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$
To do so, we can start by scaling $\DeclareMathOperator{Row}{Row}\Row_1$ by $1/2$:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 3 & -4 \\
5 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & -6 & 3
\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow{\frac{1}{2}\cdot R_1\to R_1}
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 3/2 & -2 \\
5 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & -6 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$
This row-operation corresponds to multiplying $A$ on the left by the elementary matrix
$$
E_1=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Indeed, we may check that
$$
E_1A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 3 & -4 \\
5 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & -6 & 3
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & \frac{3}{2} & -2 \\
5 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & -6 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now, every row-reduction corresponds to left-multiplication by an elementary matrix. This process yields $E_k\dotsb E_2E_1A=\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref(A)$. Hence the matrix $P$ you are interested in is $P=E_k\dotsb E_2 E_1$.

Comment: I thought this explained it. I still don't get it. Do I just multiply all the elementary matrices together? I did 9 operations to get to reduced row echelon form... not to whine this just seems wrong since that's wholly inefficient?

Comment: No, that's correct. Why does this seem "wholly inefficient"?

Comment: I was unclear sorry I thought doing 9 matrix multiplications would take forever but it didn't. I think I did it wrong though since I got a very, very wrong matrix as a result. I just multiplied E1 by E2, then that new E by E3 and that new E by E4 and so on. Did I do that wrong?

Comment: The matrix they give as the answer is: `1 0 0, -2.5 1 0, 2.9091 -1.3636 1`

whereas I got `2 0 0, 5 -11/2 0, 1 -15/2 -10`