# Can't figure out how to combine elementary matrices to get correct answer?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question originally asked "What is the matrix P that accomplishes the equivalent operations in the row reduction steps that you performed? In other words, what is the matrix P that satisfies PA = R given A and R?"

The starting matrix is here (I'm putting what I found to be the R matrix below it as well):
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
    2  &3  &−4\\
    5  &2  &1\\
    1 &−6  &3\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
R =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1  &3/2  &−2\\
    0  &1  &-2\\
    0 &0  &1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The answer I'm apparently supposed to get is here: 
$$
Correct =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1  &0  &0\\
    -2.5  &1  &0\\
    2.9091 &-1.3636  &1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And the answer I get, by combining the row operations (six of them) that I did is here. What am I getting wrong?
$$
Mine =
\begin{pmatrix}
    2  &0  &0\\
    5  &-11/2  &0\\
    1 &-15/2  &-10\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I just multiplied the inverse of the six E matrices, which amounted to just combining them into one matrix. So I'm not sure what step of this process I either omitted or didn't understand.

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: Why multiply the *inverse* of those 6 matrices? You should come up with 6 matrices which perform the individual reduction steps, and then multiply them to come up with a single matrix -- not multiply their inverses. Also, when you multiply them, make sure that the order from left to right is correct. Unlike integer multiplication, matrix multiplication is sensitive to the order of the multiplicands.

Comment: Inverse or not I get the same problem that they don't add up to the answer matrix. I was lead to believe that A^-1 = Ei ... E2 E1, so the inverse of the Es should equal regular A? Is that not right?

Comment: but that wouldn't do anything different anyways because the answer matrix has 1's as the identity matrix does and inverse or not, my answer matrix won't

Comment: You give the matrix $A$ and your answer versus the supposedly correct answer for $P$, but what is $R$? Are you supposed to be reducing $A$ to lower echelon form?

Comment: I put it in row echelon form, will edit to show R

Comment: Have you tried multiplying $A$ by the purported correct solution? That will give you an important clue to the discrepancy between that and your answer.

Comment: By the way, how is this different from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357593/what-is-the-matrix-p-that-accomplishes-the-equivalent-operations-in-the-row-re)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question aims at row operations, you'll want to start by row reducing $A$ and writing down every step of the way:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    2  &3  &−4\\
    5  &2  &1\\
    1 &−6  &3\\
\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 3/2 &-2\\
     5 & 2 &1\\
     1& -6 &3\\
\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 3/2 &-2\\
     0 & -11/2 &11\\
     1& -6 &\\
\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 3/2 &-2\\
     0 & -11/2 &11\\
     0 & -15/2 &5\\
\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 3/2 &-2\\
     0 & 1 &-2\\
     0 & -15/2 &5\\
\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 3/2 &-2\\
     0 & 1 &-2\\
     0 & 0 &-10\\
\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 3/2 &-2\\
     0 & 1 &-2\\
     0 & 0 &1\\
\end{pmatrix}=R$$
Now, as you know, all of these elementary row operations can be written as the product of elementary matrices. Example:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1/2  &0  &0\\
    0  &1  &0\\
    0 &0  &1\\
\end{pmatrix}A = \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 3/2 &-2\\
     5 & 2 &1\\
     1 & -6 &3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Let's call this resulting matrix B. Then the next step is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1  &0  &0\\
    -5  &1  &0\\
    0 &0  &1\\
\end{pmatrix}B = \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 3/2 &-2\\
     0 & -11/2 &11\\
     1& -6 &\\
\end{pmatrix}=C$$
Or in other words:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1  &0  &0\\
    -5  &1  &0\\
    0 &0  &1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    1/2  &0  &0\\
    0  &1  &0\\
    0 &0  &1\\
\end{pmatrix}A=\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 3/2 &-2\\
     0 & -11/2 &11\\
     1& -6 &\\
\end{pmatrix}=C$$
Note that if we would have numbered our row operations sequentially (1, 2, 3, etc), we now move backwards, so:
$$E_2E_1A=C$$
Let's merge the elementary matrices $E_2E_1$ to illustrate how this would work:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    1  &0  &0\\
    -5  &1  &0\\
    0 &0  &1\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    1/2  &0  &0\\
    0  &1  &0\\
    0 &0  &1\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    1/2  &0  &0\\
    -5/2  &1  &0\\
    0 &0  &1\\
\end{pmatrix}=X$$
So we can also write $$XA=C$$
If you're unsure about matrix multiplication I recommend looking at the wikipedia article, as it's quite clear on the matter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_of_the_matrix_product

Comment: See the problem is that when I do all the multiplication I get a wrong matrix, so could you walk me through a couple of those multiplications to be sure I'm doing it right?

Comment: Made some edits :)

Comment: Thank you I can't double upvote or I would!

Answer (score 0):

When there’s a discrepancy like this, it’s worth checking that the purported correct solution is actually correct. If we left-multiply $A$ by this matrix, we get $$\pmatrix{1  &0  &0\\ -2.5  &1  &0\\ 2.9091 &-1.3636  &1}\pmatrix{2  &3  &−4\\ 5  &2  &1\\ 1 &−6  &3}=\pmatrix{2.0&3.0&-4.0 \\ 0.0&-5.5&11.0 \\ 0.0002 & 0.0001&1.0}.$$ Writing off the last row as roundoff error, the important thing to note is that the diagonal entries are not all $1$. So, don’t normalize the pivots in your row-reduction, and your answer should end up matching the correct one.

In practice, an easier way to produce the matrix $P$ is to augment $A$ by an appropriately-sized identity matrix. At each step of the row-reduction process, the right-hand matrix will be the cumulative product of the elementary matrices that get you to that point.